# Doing a filter for database. Receieved error of must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#

i have received this error while doing

> the error is in the  sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FeedBackTable WHERE Reviewer = @reviewer", sqlCon);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    //they said the error was at sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    gv_feedback.DataSource = dtbl;
    gv_feedback.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Your SQL contains a parameter `@reviewer` but you did not provide that parameter to the adapter's select command.

Comment: im sorry im a beginner in this, where is the adapter's select command? is it in the gridview or my codes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill the `@reviewer` parameter.

```
var cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM FeedBackTable WHERE Reviewer = @reviewer";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr,con);
cmd.Parameter.add(new SqlParameter("@reviewer", theValueOfTheReviewer);
var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var dtbl =new Datatable();
sqlDa.fill(dtbl);
```

Comment: Yes, but you have syntax errors. You might want to fix them before OP says it doesn't work.

Comment: i apologise, i still dont get it, am i suppose to replace my codes or add some of them to my codes?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the @reviewer parameter and set its value. Put the value where it says "reviewerIdHere".

```
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FeedBackTable WHERE Reviewer = @reviewer", sqlCon);
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reviewer",reviewerIdHere); 
    //they said the error was at sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
}
gv_feedback.DataSource = dtbl;
gv_feedback.DataBind();
```

Comment: You may want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, no I don't need to. Check OP's code before saying that. It wouldn't be the only thing one would like to stop using. If you like you can allocate a big time to show him how to do that, I was lazy. And you should not only point to some reading, but really read it to understand what it is saying. Here it is nonsense to point to it.